# TSQL MS SQL Server Concatenate declared variable in a Procedure into SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a procedure where I can programmatically change the columns in the query based on parameters passed. I'm trying to concatenate the variable to the column field but am unable to. I have been able to achieve this in excel vba by concatenating using " & v_variable & " and it works perfectly. I'm hoping to achieve the same in my stored procedure so I can move my code from excel vba file to the server for many good reasons. One big reason being that copies of this excel file is used by several people and any changes in the code becomes a nightmare to maintain and distribute. Thanks in advance.

1. I need to concatenate the variable @v_PriceDeltaType to 'Event' (see the case statement in the snippet). Basically I want the program to literally replace the variable value in the query in order to achieve the desired query I have shown below. I need this because the value of the variable can change in order to fetch data from a different column in the view from which the data is coming.
2. The query example below is a tiny snippet from a massive 5 union query around 60 lines. So I'm hoping the solutions suggested would aim at helping me with concatenating the variables to the query rather than chaning the whole architecture of my query. Otherwise I'll take whatever works.

Below is my procedure snippet:

```
DECLARE @v_PriceDeltaType varchar(10) = 'PML_Delta', 
        @v_EventDate Date = '2017-07-18', 
        @v_WXRegion varchar(10) = 'ALL', 
        @v_Weekend int = 0, 
        @HistHEWinDays int = 3, 
        @v_HistDeltaWin int = 4

SELECT Cast(@v_EventDate as Date) EventDate, Event.Hit, Event.Point, 
       (CASE 
       WHEN AVG(Event.@v_PriceDeltaType) < 0 THEN 'OFF' 
       WHEN AVG(Event.@v_PriceDeltaType) >= 0 THEN 'ON' 
       ELSE 'Error' END ) EventType

FROM [PowerEvent].[dbo].[v_4_WXL] Event 
WHERE WXFDate = @v_EventDate 
and LFFEventDate = WXFDate 
and LFFRegion = '@v_WXRegion' 
and MDDHWeekend = @v_Weekend 
GROUP BY Event.Point, Event.Hit 
HAVING Count(Event.Hit) > @HistHEWinDays 
And Abs(AVG(Event.@v_PriceDeltaType)) > @v_HistDeltaWin
```

Desired Query: I'd like to have my query looking like this when it runs.

```
SELECT '2017-07-18' EventDate, Event.Hit, Event.Point, 
        (CASE 
        WHEN AVG(Event.PML_Delta) < 0 THEN 'OFF' 
        WHEN AVG(Event.PML_Delta) >= 0 THEN 'ON' 
        ELSE 'Error' END ) EventType

FROM [PowerEvent].[dbo].[v_4_WXL] Event 
WHERE WXFDate = '2017-07-18' 
and LFFEventDate = WXFDate 
and LFFRegion = 'ALL' and MDDHWeekend = 0 
GROUP BY Event.Point, Event.Hit 
HAVING Count(Event.Hit) > 3 And Abs(AVG(Event.PML_Delta)) > 4
```

Comment: what happens when you run this?

Comment: You need to make this dynamic. that's your issue.

Comment: @Eli- I get the following error message when i run it.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '@v_PriceDeltaType'.

Comment: @KeithL- The query is way too big to make it into a dynamic and even the minor  code changes would take lots of time and effort. So I assume there's no solution for concatenation?

Comment: @Bobby Is the query you have there the entire query, or have you shortened it for posting here?  As written in the question, it looks like making this a dynamic SQL query would be a relatively easy change.

Comment: @Paul Williams - its just a tiny part of a really big query and thats why i'm avoiding dynamic sql query.

Comment: I'm really surprised Microsoft allows direct insertion/concatenation of variables in Excel vba but not sql server procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dynamic sql -- this might take some finessing as I did not test it but hopefully gets you going:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)  

DECLARE @v_PriceDeltaType varchar(10) = 'PML_Delta', 
        @v_EventDate Date = '2017-07-18', 
        @v_WXRegion varchar(10) = 'ALL', 
        @v_Weekend int = 0, 
        @HistHEWinDays int = 3, 
        @v_HistDeltaWin int = 4



set @sql = 
'
SELECT Cast('''+convert(Varchar(10),@v_EventDate,101) +''' as Date) EventDate, 
       Event.Hit, 
       Event.Point, 
       (CASE 
       WHEN AVG(Event.['+@v_PriceDeltaType+']) < 0 THEN ''OFF'' 
       WHEN AVG(Event.['+@v_PriceDeltaType+']) >= 0 THEN ''ON'' 
       ELSE ''Error'' END ) EventType

FROM [PowerEvent].[dbo].[v_4_WXL] Event 
WHERE WXFDate = '''+convert(varchar(10),@v_EventDate,101)+'''
and LFFEventDate = WXFDate 
and LFFRegion = '''+@v_WXRegion+'''
and MDDHWeekend = '+convert(varchar(10), @v_Weekend) + '
GROUP BY Event.Point, Event.Hit 
HAVING Count(Event.Hit) > '+convert(Varchar(10),@HistHEWinDays) + '
And Abs(AVG(Event.['+@v_PriceDeltaType+'])) > '+convert(varchar(10), @v_HistDeltaWin) +'
'

print @sql
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but I do believe this will run just fine.  Print out the SQL and see if you think that would run or not.

Comment: Jesse thanks for the dynamic sql example that you nicely put together. In my original request I asked for a concatenation solution and I'm going to keep the dynamic sql solution as the absolute last resort. The real query is now almost 80 lines long and having a concatenation of variables solution will be lot easier than converting the whole query into dynamic sql. Hope this makes it clear. thanks for the help though.

Comment: Hi Bobby, ok I am not totally sure what you mean by concatenation of variables in your example I do not see any other way to do this but with dynamic sql.  For example, converting a variable that holds a column name into using the actual column is exactly what dynamic sql is used for.  Anyhow, you never know, maybe there is some way I am not thinking of now.  Good luck.

Comment: Jesse: look at my code snippet I provided in my question. Notice the Case statement which has the line WHEN AVG(Event.v_PriceDeltaType). In this line 'Event' is the alias for the table and v_PriceDeltaType is the variable that holds the column name that is being passed. If I were able to successfully concatenate the variable to the table alias then the query at run time would look like WHEN AVG(Event.PML_Delta). 'PML_Delta is the value passed to the parameter v_PriceDeltaType. So that's what I mean by concatenation. Based on many factors the value (ie col name) passed to variable can change

Comment: Right and that is exactly what dynamic sql does.  Not sure of any other way to do it.

Comment: I'm bummed but I guess I'll have to give in. And also very disappointed that Microsoft provide that feature in sql server but it does very nicely in Excel VBA for over 2 decades.

Comment: Used the dynamic sql approach to the solution and its working really well. Took forever to reformat the massive query. The blessing disguise was that it refreshed what my query was doing. Had to make some correcting modifications to Jessie's beautiful code. Thanks Keith and Jesse.